# What are the effects of charging a laptop on Javascript Game for Windows 8

Tags: javascript, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Game using JavaScript and HTML5 .While using the concept of canvas ,I am rendering the images on screen and then moving the coordinates to make the image look moving. When the laptop is charging the images move very fast but as soon as  it is unplugged ,the speed of image falls.

Comment: Your system is probably throttling its CPU to conserve power or minimize heat output.

Comment: That has nothing to do with JS, it's the power-management settings of the machine. If you're working on the battery, you can set your laptop to reduce the CPU's clock (ie a 2.4Ghz code could well be switched back to 1.6Ghz). If it's an iX processor the external GPU will probably be switched off all together and all rendering will be done by the GPU that's on the processor chip (which is a lot slower, too) There's nothing you can do about that: you can't control how the client configuers his/her machine. If its just for personal use, you can turn off all power-saving settings

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows laptops you've got power options which are designed by default to reduce a processor and video performance if a laptop unplugged from a charger. Also if your browser for game's debugging is IE the windows also will reduce javascript performance for IE.  The first Google link for illustrating my words: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/778-power-plan-settings-change.html (you've got the same options for Windows 8).